# How to bulk rename files within subfolders - using CMD command prompt

Tags: file, cmd, subdirectory, renaming

I am quite new to Command Prompt (Windows), however I have used it to do some file extensions changing and it is extremely helpful. I know nothing on coding, and so i am simply going off what I have read about but I am looking for a command line that I cant seem to find anywhere. I have folder, and inside that folder are 70 sub folders each labelled by a number from 1-70. Inside these subfolders are roughly 20 png picture files, that are currently numbered by a number from 1-20 in png format. I am looking for a command line to rename each file from its original name to "folder name (page number).png"

For example, I have folder called '68' and inside that folder is 1.png, 2.png, 3.png. I want the command line to change that 1.png and 2.png etc... to 68 (1).png and 68 (2). png, noticing the space between the bracket and the folder name. Sorry if i have made it confusing but I would really appreciate it and I have got some very helpful and quick answers from StackOverflow before

Thankyou if you are able to help me, as i am completely hopeless on this matter.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that with one command but you can write a script to open folders and then `mv` your png file. But that would be bash scripting and it's not a single command as you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Only run this once - launch it from the folder containing the 70 folders.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b') do (
pushd "%%a"
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /a-d /b') do ren "%%b" "%%a (%%~nb)%%~xb"
popd
)
```

Comment: Sorry to sound like such an ammature but i am having a lot of trouble figuring out how any of these codes work. Without sounding too lazy, what would be ideal if possible would be a command line that i could copy directly into command prompt without having to do multiple processes if possible. Also it would be best to be able to specify a file path rather than having to change the directory would be ideal. Sorry to sound unexperienced but i cannot seem to understand any of the language or the processors and am just looking for a simple command line where i specify the file path and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a very experienced bash scriptor, but I guess this should do the task for you. I am assuming that you are using Linux operating system. So open a text editor and copy the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

NumberOfFolders=70

for((a=1; a <= NumberOfFolders ; a++))
do
        cd ./$a
        b=1
        while [ -f $b.png ]
        do
                mv "$b.png" "$a($b).png"
                let b=b+1
        done
        cd ..
done
```

save this script where you have you folders 1-70 (and call it whatever.ssh). Then open a terminal and write down `chmod a+x whatever.ssh` and after that `./whatever.ssh`. This should do the job as you presented in your question.

Comment: No sorry @MRZ I am using windows 7 - and I was looking for a command line for the windows command prompt (CMD)

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification of the approach [@foxidrive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16250630/1630171) suggested, so the script can be run from anywhere and won't have to parse `dir` output:

```
@echo off
for /r "C:\root\folder" %%d in (.) do (
  pushd "%%~fd"
  for %%f in (*) do ren "%%~ff" "%%~nd (%%~nf)%%~xf"
  popd
)
```

Note that this will not work in Windows XP (not sure about Windows Vista), due to a bug with the expansion of `*` in the inner `for` loop that would cause the files to be renamed multiple times.

Comment: This is flawed because of a long standing bug with a plain for in do command, where it will process files twice+ when you change the filespec it is processing.

Comment: Please provide evidence for this claim. The code did not rename anything twice when I tested it.

Comment: Some further investigation showed that this was a bug in Windows XP, but apparently it was fixed in Windows 7.

Comment: In my tests it is still a bug in Windows 8 (and it existed since MSDos 3.1 at least) - try it with a large number of files.  Say 100.

Comment: I have some sample code to demonstrate it but not sure where to post it.

Comment: I tried with about 500 files in 1 folder, names generated as `!random!.txt`. As for the sample code, pastebins are a common way of sharing stuff like that.

Comment: Try this code.  It is reproducible here and the last files show the issue. http://www.astronomy.comoj.com/test_forindo_problem.bat

Comment: I see. However, this issue is different from what I observed on XP, where the rename tight-looped.