# Bulk renaming files in relation to the folder names

Tags: cmd, rename, subdirectory, bulk

I am very new to coding and bulk processes but i am looking for a command line SPECIFICALLY for windows command prompt and i am wondering if such a thing exists. So I have a folder containing 111 subfolders, with each subfolder containing between 20 and 40 png image files. Each subfolder is named 001-111 accordingly and the png files are ordered how i want them, however i am looking for a command line that would be able to quickly and efficiently name all the pngs in the folders to the name of the folder followed by the png number in brackets

e.g. for folder 037, i would want the png's to be renamed to:    **037(1), 037(2), 037(3)** etc...

I am hoping for the best although i am unsure such a code may not be possible or be simply done.

Also if you come up with a code that achieves this process, it would be great if you could reply with the simple command line that i could use rather than a full explanation because i am new to coding and far from fluent with the language or terms or how things work. I know this same process can be achieved by going    *select all>rename (ctrl a>f2)*    and renaming to the folder name however i need to use this process frequently and dont want to have to open each folder, i would rather have a command line for cmd that would do it swiftly

Thank you and a simple answer would be greatly appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248730/how-to-bulk-rename-files-within-subfolders-using-cmd-command-prompt

Comment: [philosophy] It's a sad state of affairs when people don't want to know and don't want to find out. But I'll admit to being the same when it comes to matters automotive. It becomes tragic when this increasingly-common attitude is encountered in people who claim to be qualified in the subject under discussion. We can't all be Edisons, but if everyone were to adopt this attitude, we'd still be living in caves.[/philosophy]

Comment: Note that 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 will not sort correctly in a folder. The usual solution is to pad the filenames as in 0001 0002

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "parentdir=u:\parent"
FOR /l %%a IN (1001,1,1111) DO (
 SET dir=%%a&SET "dir=!dir:~1!"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /a-d /b "%parentdir%\!dir!\*.png" 2^>nul') DO (
  ECHO REN "%parentdir%\!dir!\%%~nxi" "!dir!(%%~ni)%%~xi"
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Test results:
Starting directory :

```
u:\parent\001\1.png
u:\parent\037\1.png
u:\parent\037\2.png
u:\parent\111\999 with spaces in name.png
```

Script response

```
REN "u:\parent\001\1.png" "001(1).png"
REN "u:\parent\037\1.png" "037(1).png"
REN "u:\parent\037\2.png" "037(2).png"
REN "u:\parent\111\999 with spaces in name.png" "111(999 with spaces in name).png"
```

Obviously, you'd need to replace the value assigned to `parentdir` with your actual target directory name.

The script will report the renames it proposes to do. To actually invoke the `rename` remove the `ECHO` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a batch file like so:

renamepng.bat:

```
cd %%1
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto end
for %f in *.png do mv "%f" "%%1(%f).png" 
cd ..
:end
```

This will attempt to cd to the directory name provided on the command line, abort if that fails, then rename all the .png files and return to the previous directory

then call it like so:

```
for %d in ??? do call renamepng.bat %d
```

which will loop through all 3-character file and directory names in the current directory, can call the batch file on each one.  Using call instead of just the batch file name causes execution to return to the loop when the batch finishes.